# graphql-java-annotations: Argument must be annotated with @GraphQLName, otherwise it would fail

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

If i don't add `@GraphQLName("name")`, then method would not be recognized correctly! (version: 0.13.2)

```
@GraphQLField
@GraphQLDataFetcher(MyDataFetcher.class)
public String findByName(@GraphQLName("name") String name){
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile your class with following javac option: `-parameters`

More detailed you could refer my [submitted issue on Github](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-annotations/issues/51).